# Django Dynamic formset: correct usage with inline formsets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

I am using Django Formsets to make invoices (need to add items, people, materials etc.). To be able to add and delete formsets, I am using [Django Dynamic Formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset). However, this plugin seems to be no longer maintained and while it seems to work fine for modelformsets, the problem arises with inline formsets.
I am using this logic to select the number of extra forms I need for the view(where you can modify your invoice)

```
costi_offerta_inline = forms.inlineformset_factory(offerta_impianti,
                            offerta_impianti_costi, 
                            form=offerta_impianti_costi_form, extra=0)\
    if (offerta_impianti_costi.objects.filter(offerta_ref=instance).count() > 0) \
    else forms.inlineformset_factory(offerta_impianti, offerta_impianti_costi, 
        form=offerta_impianti_costi_form, extra=1)
```

Problem is that doing this(it's probably not the reason, but you never know) the formsets act weird. If I add a new form, it works fine. Total Forms updates adding plus one and form is displayed correctly. But when I try to remove one, Total Forms doesn't decrement and I'm left with an extra form that blocks all validation from happening.

Can someone help me?

Comment: this is probably related to your javascript. You do need to decrement the total forms hidden input field using javascript when you try to delete a form (besides marking the input fields as deleted)

Comment: that's what the script is supposed to do(and does on modelformsets). It behaves weirdly on inline modelformsets, without a good reason(apparently)

Comment: Well then you should show your javascript

Comment: I am using a plugin that can be found here: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: The github docs says “Create an inline formset, making sure to pass can_delete=True in the call to inlineformset_factory.“. Do you have it?

Comment: tried adding it, nothing changed